# CKEDITOR 4.3 surrounding data with tags?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, ckeditor

I'm using CKEDITOR in version 4.3 and got sections of a html as input.

Now i need to make sure, that the costum-data always got a root tag (in my case a div with the class='CKEDITOR-autoadd).

so when my input is:

```
<p>jkdhgjkhngvkh</p>
<p>shgnuvzv</p>
```

my output has to be

```
<div class='CKEDITOR-autoadd'>
    <p>jkdhgjkhngvkh</p>
    <p>shgnuvzv</p>
</div>
```

Does anyone got an idea how i could solve this?
I had the idea of adding a custom plugin like

```
if(!root-tag found){
  add div
}
```

Summary 2 Problems:
1. How do I surround my custom-data with tags? 
2. How do I check / search a root-tag?

regards Sebastian

Edit: the failure in the Java-Applikation happens when:

```
public Element addSection(String title, String xmlAsString, String lang) throws IOException, JDOMException {
    Content content = null;      
    try {
        SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlAsString);
      →  Document doc = saxBuilder.build(reader); ← ERROR = JDOMParseException
        content = doc.getRootElement();
        content.detach();
    }catch (JDOMParseException jdomParseExc) {
        content = new Text(xmlAsString);
    }
    return this.addSection(title, content, lang);
}
```

Comment: This depends a lot on how you save and load your data, could you show the code for that? Do you want the solution to be serverside or clientside? If serverside; what language?

Comment: the input is saved via JAVA per JSON arrray, that works all fine, but my Java-Application doesn't recognize my data as valid xml if there is no root-tag, the failure happens, when (have a look at my edit)

Comment: I'd just do a simple workaround like `if (!xmlAsString.Trim().StartsWith("<div class='CKEDITOR-autoadd'")) { xmlAsString = "<div class='CKEDITOR-autoadd'>" + xmlAsString + "</div>"; }` or if it's really just for XML validation without a schema, just add a stupid div every time: `xmlAsString = "<div>" + xmlAsString + "</div>";` - empty divs cause no harm (usually ;P). Would that work for you?

Comment: Ach derp, my example is in c# and doesn't even compile but you get the idea :D If it works I'll add as answer but not yet because it's not very elegant.